# How to Use Copy Constructor?

Tags: java, copy

I am making a mini Twitter.

One of the methods is a pseudo copy constructor and I'm confused how to go about this.

The method takes an existing user, a new `userID`, and a boolean flag.

It should create a new user with the `newID` given, and the same tweets as the old user that is being passed in.

Information about the number of followers or list of users the old user is following should not be copied.

If the flag is `false`, make a shallow copy of the old user's tweet `ArrayList`, otherwise make a deep copy. Never make a reference copy.

All other instance variables should be initialized appropriately. It may help you to call the earlier constructor here.

These are my instance variables and the copy constructor method:

```
public class TwitterUser {
    private String userID2;
    private ArrayList<Tweet> listTweets;
    private ArrayList<TwitterUser> toFollow;
    private long numberFollowers;
    private int numTweets;
    private int numberFollowing;

public TwitterUser(TwitterUser old, String newID, boolean flag) {

}
```

I am thinking to do this, but am not sure if I am on the right track:

```
public TwitterUser(TwitterUser old, String newID, boolean flag) {
        if (flag == true) {
            userID2 = newID;
            listTweets = old.listTweets;
            toFollow = old.toFollow;

        }
}
```

**EDIT**

I also need to return a shallow (NOT reference or deep) copy of the list of users that this user is following. I was thinking to use `.clone` but I'm not sure how to. This is the constructor:

```
    public ArrayList<TwitterUser> getFollowing() {
        return toFollow.clone();
    }
```

Comment: As a note, `flag` is an unhelpful name for a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Here you do a shallow copy while the flag is true. That is not what it is asked in your exercice.
Besides, you should handle both cases :

```
public TwitterUser(TwitterUser old, String newID, boolean isDistinctListTweets) {
        // common processing
        userID2 = newID;
        if (!isDistinctListTweets) { 
            // shallow copy of the tweets
            listTweets = new ArrayList<>(old.listTweets);  
        }
        else{
            // deep copy of the tweets
            listTweets = new ArrayList<>(old.listTweets.size());  
            for (Tweet tweet : old.listTweets) {
               // add a copy constructor in Tweet too     
               listTweets.add(new Tweet(tweet)); 
            }
        } 
}
```

Note that in the shallow copy, the tweets of the two `TwitterUser` objects refer to the same objects while the list that contains them refers to a different object.   It makes sense  since we don't want to synchronize the two list state for the whole life of the objects.

With Java 8 you could shortcut the `else` statement in this way :

```
else{
    // deep copy of the tweets
    listTweets = old.listTweets
                    .stream() 
                    .map(Tweet::new)
                    .collect(toList());
}
```

Beyond your exercice I would model the requirement with two factory methods to make the API clearer :

```
public static TwitterUser copyWithDistinctTweets(TwitterUser old, String newID) { ... }

public static TwitterUser copyShallow(TwitterUser old, String newID) { ... }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "we don't want to synchronize the two list state for the whole life of the objects."?